# Google drive as database(storing all user's document ) for flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I need to store all users' document (one per user) in a single google drive. NOT store in each user's own google drive. And after storing I need to get the link of that document. I am not able to find the answer for 'how to use a single drive to store all the users' data?'.

If this is possible and anyone who knows how to do it, please help we the the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a commercial cloud storage offering, such as GCP Cloud Storage.

Comment: 1. you could use a service account to upload these files,   2. link to the document would be a web link but google drive one make that for every type of file, you will have issues with permission of these files as they will be owned by the service account and your users wont have access to them.   May i suggest you go with @Julia solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the use of your application and the files?